# How can I create a model to store data from Database with accented letters?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asp.net-core

Normally when a stored procedure is called, we have to set up a model for it. So a basic model would be like this.

Database:

```
TABLE [dbo].[ExampleWithAccentedLetters](
    [Ngay] [DateTime] ,
    [Ma_Cttv] [int]
```

[image: Database item column without accented letters]

Then my object model is easy and simple to set up with just:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public DateTime Ngay { get; set; }
    public int Ma_Cttv { get; set; }
}
```

But what if a stored procedure returns me a table with a column with accented letters or special characters like this.

```
TABLE [dbo].[ExampleWithAccentedLetters](
    [Ngay] [DateTime] ,
    [Ma_Cttv] [int]
    [Điện tự phát] [int]
```

[image: Database with accented letters column title]

How can I implement my model now?

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I would fix it now.

Comment: Looks like you are getting data as column names. Avoid that and return whatever name as a dataset even if it's a single row. You can let your stored procedure return two query results in one go. ADO.Net has a mechanism to get both results.

Comment: Just change yourself or request change to SP to normalize the query `select [Điện tự phát] as column1`... Are you using Entity Framework - then decorate columns. I don't understand how that field interferes with loading a model?

Comment: How are you loading the results? For Entity Framework, while your c# property name must meet c# naming rules, you can map a property to any db column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ColumnAttribute could work here:

```
public class DataModel
{
    public DateTime Ngay { get; set; }

    public int Ma_Cttv { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "Điện tự phát")]
    int Column3 {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you can't just rename the column which would probably easiest solution. You might have to return a view and rename the column in the view. You can create model classes for views like you can for tables.

EDIT

You can create a view and rename it's columns so your c# class can use the new non-accented column name(s) like so:

```
create view nonAccentedView (Ngay, Ma_Cttv, DienTuPhat)
as
select [Ngay], [Ma_Cttv], [Điện tự phát]
from [dbo].[ExampleWithAccentedLetters]
```

Now your c# class can look like this when you return the view:

```
public class NonAccentedView {
    public DateTime Ngay { get; set; }
    public int Ma_Cttv { get; set; }
    public int DienTuPhat { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I can rename it. It just that my colleague said that if in others' code they need to recycle my code and those code aiming to understand accented letters, it would make them unable to work anymore.

Comment: @AdminCapstone That's understandable, in that case you should return a view. You can specify a new column name for views and I'll edit my answer to give an example.